# Maple: patmatch does not identify patterns inside diff() operator

Tags: symbolic-computation, maple

I understand that the function `applyrule` uses `patmatch` to identify patterns and apply transformations accordingly.

Suppose, I want to write a rule for transforming spatial derivatives along $z-$direction of field components $E_i(x,y,z)$ to momentum space, so that:

> $\partial_{z}(E_i(x,y,z)) \to -ikE_i(x,y,z)$.

I tried to define a rule as follows:

```
In: applyrule(diff(f::function,z)=-I*k*f,diff(E1(x, y, z), z))
Out: diff(E1(x, y, z), z)
```

It does not work. The reason is, patmatch is unable to match the above pattern:

```
In: patmatch(diff(E1(x, y, z), z), diff(f::function, z))
Out: false
```

On the contrary, if there is no `diff()` operator,

```
In: patmatch(E1(x, y, z), f::function)
Out: true
```

As a workaround, I currently write the following command:

```
applyrule(diff(dE1(X), z) = -I*k*dE1(X),expression)
```

for each field component in `expression` and it works fine.

But I would like to know an easier way to do this so that I don't have to write the rules for each component separately. Specifically, the inability of `patmatch` to identify pattern inside `diff()` is troubling. Any workaround or solution to resolve this would be helpful.